# Filtering two arrays with .filter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get information, a have all the data that i get from Database and now I need to do something that should be simple (but not for a novice like me xd), I'm trying to do the next filter in JS

```
const array1 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: '8'}, {id: 'c'}, {id: 'a'}];
const array2 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'c'}];
console.log(array1.filter(id => id.id == array2.id))
```

It doesn't returns me nothing, and I don't understand why, also I try to use:

```
console.log(array1.filter(id => id.id == array2.id))
```

My result is all the values from array1, I mean I only want the elements that have the same Id that array2 from array1, in other words, I want that its returns me 2 objects with Id = a and one with id = c

Comment: `It doesn't returns me nothing` - so it returns everything? ;)

Comment: If you want a somewhat non-verbose way of writing this I would, instead of native filter+some use lodashs intersectionBy function.

    _.intersectionBy(array1, array2, 'id');

It's a pretty neat way to get the intended results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inside [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback method.

```js
const array1 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: '8'}, {id: 'c'}, {id: 'a'}];
const array2 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'c'}];
const output = array1.filter(item1 => array2.some(item2 => item2.id === item1.id))
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return three objects, because in array1 there are two objects with id: a and one with id: c.

```js
const array1 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: '8'}, {id: 'c'}, {id: 'a'}];
const array2 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'c'}];
let res = array1.filter(obj1 => array2.find(obj2 => obj1.id === obj2.id))

console.log(res)
```

You can filter out duplicate objects with `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const array1 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: '8'}, {id: 'c'}, {id: 'a'}];
const array2 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'c'}];
let res = array1.filter(obj1 => {
  return array2.find(obj2 => obj1.id === obj2.id)
})
.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  if(!acc.find(obj => obj.id === cur.id)){
    acc.push(cur)
  }
  return acc
},[])

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if `array2` has an element with a given `id`:

```js
const array1 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: '8'}, {id: 'c'}, {id: 'a'}];
const array2 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'c'}];

const res = array1.filter(({id}) => array2.some(e => e.id===id));

console.log(res);
```

A better way would be using a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const array1 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: '8'}, {id: 'c'}, {id: 'a'}];
const array2 = [{id: 'a'}, {id: 'c'}];

const idsInArray2 = new Set(array2.map(({id}) => id));
const res = array1.filter(({id}) => idsInArray2.has(id));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and filter the array.

This approach takes a single loop for building the set and another for filtering.

```js
const
    array1 = [{ id: 'a' }, { id: '8' }, { id: 'c' }, { id: 'a' }],
    array2 = [{ id: 'a' }, { id: 'c' }],
    set2 = new Set(array2.map(({ id }) => id)),
    result = array1.filter(({ id }) => set2.has(id));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```